# buttons not styled in jQM popup launched from code

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

I'm using jQM popup to 'alert' users of something. For example, I make a `$.ajax()` request and if there's something wrong with the response I shoot a popup.
Something like this:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popup">
    <p id="popupMsg"></p>
</div>

$("#popupMsg").html(msg);
$("#popup").popup({
    history:false,
    overlayTheme: "a"
}).popup('open');
```

It all works fine, but If I change the popup to include a button, this way:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popup">
    <p id="popupMsg"></p>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Ok</a>
</div>
```

Then the link is not styled, and it will just show an 'Ok' link.
If I move the popup to a dialog then it all works, button and all, but since I want the page underneath to be seen, I'd like to keep it a popup.

Am I missing something? I saw a lot of questions about popups/dialogs, but they all refer to clicking a button to show them.
I use jquery-1.8.2 and jquery.mobile-1.2.0.

---

**Edit**: the solution to my case is that the popup `div` must go *inside* the page `div`, and not outside of it (as a dialog `div` would), like this:

*Before (wrong)*:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        ...page stuff...
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="popup" id="popup">
    <p id="popupMsg"></p>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Ok</a>
</div>
```

*After (right)*:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        ...page stuff...
        <div data-role="popup" id="popup">
            <p id="popupMsg"></p>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Ok</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refresh the jQM markup

- http://jsfiddle.net/xvvCA/1/
- http://jsfiddle.net/xvvCA/ ( inline button )

JS

```
var msg = 'Look! A new button!';

$("#popupMsg").html(msg);
$("#popup").popup({
    history:false,
    overlayTheme: "a"
}).popup('open');

$('#okButton').button('refresh'); // you need to refresh jQM markup
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">

        <div data-role="popup" id="popup">
            <p id="popupMsg"></p>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c" id="okButton">Ok</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually it's not that. It's because the popup div must be inside the page div, while i had it outside (as the dialog div). Not really clear from the docs that this is the way to do it.
Anyway, it was thanks to your fiddle that i found the solution, so I'll accept it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: As I had the same issue and Stephen's solution to place the popup inside the page div hasn't worked for me I tried your suggestion. You get the following error:  
  
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization;  
  
This seems reasonable enough. JQM has not found the buttons and they exist in the DOM only as links.   
  
The sequence of method calls I followed is the same: 
1. popup()
2. popup("open")
3. $("#...").button("refresh")

Comment: Applying el.trigger("create") works !!

    pop$.popup("open");
    pop$.trigger("create");